# Powershell Scripting regarding decrementing dates by one

Tags: powershell

Here is my script so far. My intention is to take the event log from the previous day and send it an email to myself every morning. This is my script so far.

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName Application -After "10/26/16" | ConvertTo-Html | set-content 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Powershell Outputs\1day event log.html')
$date= get-date 
if ($date=get-date).AddDays(-1) 
Else {"File Not Found"}`
Send-MailMessage -To "my email" -From "my email" -subject "Eventlog for Yesterday" -body "This is a daily sent automated email for the event log of the previous day." -Attachments "`
```

Now what am I doing wrong, Im brand new to powershell so go easy.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing you are going to want to do is get Yesterday in a `DateTime`, which is what I assume you were trying to do with `$date` and `if ($date = (get-date).AddDays(-1))`

Then let's put you log location in a variable, so that we can use it both in saving the log and then sending the attachment

The `-After` parameter uses the `DateTime` that we saved in `$Yesterday`. The path for `Set-Content` is then `$logPath`

```
#Get DateTime for Yesterday
$Yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
#Set the location of the log attachment
$logPath = 'C:\Users\myusername\Documents\Powershell Outputs\1day event log.html'
#Get the Event Log After Yesterday, Convert it to HTML, Save it to the logPath
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -After $Yesterday | ConvertTo-Html | Set-Content $logPath
#Send Mail Message with the logPath as an attachment
Send-MailMessage -To "my email" -From "my email" -subject "Eventlog for Yesterday" -body "This is a daily sent automated email for the event log of the previous day." -Attachments $logpath
```